# Oracle unique constraint on PK violated

Tags: oracle

I have a stored proc that I call from an external program to upsert data. The way the proc is setup is that it inserts into the table and on exception 'dup_val_on_index' it does an update instead.

How could I get this error if I'm catching the 'dup_val_on_index' exception and doing an update inside of it? I assume a PK would catch this specific exception since it creates a duplicate?

Comment: `I have a stored proc` where is it?

Comment: I don't like showing production code on the site. I guess my first question is, would a PK unique constraint be caught by the dup_val_on_index exception?

Comment: Do you have any more information you can share? there is nothing here that will help people solve your problem since all we know is you have an error and something in place that is supposed to catch it.

Comment: We are not interested in your production code. You should give a simplified example anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the dup_val_on_index named error would be raised for a primary key constraint error.

Perhaps your update is the code that is causing the error to be raised.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) in the first place?

In case you really don't want to use merge, just build an inner pl/sql-block and catch the exception there:

```
create or replace procedure proc(param1 varchar2)
as
some_var varchar2(50);
begin
  -- do some things
  begin
    insert on your table;
    exception when dup_val_on_index then
      update on your table;
  end;
  --proceed with some more things
end proc;
```